# How do i execute an observable when the return is not necessary

Tags: angular, observable

I plan to make a post to execute a print. I don't need anything returned from this call. I've been executing my calls by using `.subscribe(x => this.data = x)` knowing that I don't need anything returned, is it possible to execute this observable call with out using `.subscribe(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official tutorial, just call `subscribe()` on it.

```
this.heroService.deleteHero(hero).subscribe();
```

https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#delete-a-hero

You need to call subscribe, otherwise, the observable will do nothing until someting is subscribed to it.

Comment: There are other methods of executing the observable without calling `subscribe` yourself. For instance, you could use `toPromise()` instead.

Comment: @arieljuod thank you! This is what i needed to know.